# Editable UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set up a UITableView that I can edit. I have the following methods implemented:

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

but I'm not sure how to link editing to an edit button in my UINavigationBar. Here is my button item:

```
UIBarButtonItem * leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
                                                               target:nil 
                                                               action:@selector(editButtonSelected:)];
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a lot of success just using the standard edit button:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

The problem with your code is that you didn't set a target. If the editButtonSelected: selector is in the view controller where you are setting this up, use "self" like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editButtonSelected:)];
```

Comment: That's a different question. First, try the standard edit button. It will set the editing property of the table view to YES and change the button title and appearance to Done.